# Place holder text is missing and back space not working in masked text box

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have used the masked textbox in asp.net c# application

```
     <div class="span3">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtExpiryDate" placeholder="(mm-dd-yy)" CssClass="datepiker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"
                            Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtExpiryDate"><b>Enter Renewal Date</b></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator Display="Dynamic" ID="valdRegStartDate" runat="server"
                            ControlToValidate="txtExpiryDate" ErrorMessage="Enter a valid Expiry Date." ValidationExpression="([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[012])([-/.])([1-9]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([-/.])(19[5-9][0-9]|20[0-4][0-9])"><b>Enter a valid Expiry Date.</b>
                        </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        <cc1:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskDate" Enabled="true" runat="server" MaskType="Date"
                         Mask="99-99-9999" TargetControlID="txtExpiryDate" MessageValidatorTip="true" ClearMaskOnLostFocus="false">
                        </cc1:MaskedEditExtender>  

                    </div>
```

The placeholder (mm-dd-yy) in the textbox is not displayed and backspace is not working.

It displays placeholder as `__-__-____` instead of `(mm-dd-yy)`.

Please help me !!!

Answer (score 1):

Remove placeholder in your markup and try this in your **Page_Load**:

```
txtExample.Attributes.Add("placeholder","mm/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: I want to use both calendar and masked textbox

Comment: @Nida use placeholder in Page_Load... i edit my post now.

Answer (score 1):

The `MaskedEditExtender` is overriding your placeholder. That's why you're seeing `__-__-____` (according to the mask). You can't really have both so one will have to give. You already have the regular expression validator (which is checking for a 4-digit year) so I suggest removing the MaskedEditExtender and tweaking your validator.

I'd even go as far as saying using a `CustomValidator` to clean up the markup a little.